# Marvel Unlimited - comics aimed at young children

Tags: marvel, marvel-unlimited

My oldest son is five.  He's already a capable reader and is becoming very interested in super heroes.  He's watched *Avengers*, after his mother and I previewed it.  He didn't seem terribly interested in the talky bits, but loved the action sequences.

We've picked up a few books for him - books aimed at younger kids learning to read - that feature his favorite heroes.  The problem we have is that his 3-year old brother and a family friend's kid we babysit tend to destroy them quite quickly.

It's frankly getting expensive to replace and supplement these things at $8 each, and I've yet to discover a way to get a trio of young children to not fight over the books.

I'm considering a subscription to Marvel Unlimited, but I can't find much in the way of details about the service.  I know there are many comics I would not yet want my son to read - he doesn't have the emotional maturity to handle something like *Civil War*, but I know it's one thing heavily advertised.

Does Marvel Unlimited have appropriate titles for younger children?  Is there a way to limit what can be seen?

Comment: To be clear, you're planning on replacing the kids' $8 comic books with $200+ tablets?  Just saying, that doesn't seem like it'll fix the cost-of-replacement issue.

Comment: Nope, we plan to let the older child (only) use our computer under supervision.  If we had a tablet, it would be Daddy's, and the kids know that. :-D

Comment: The CCA-approved golden and silver age superhero comics should be alright for young children. They weren't even allowed to contain werewolves, zombies, vampires, etc., have the words "horror" or "terror" in the title or portray "policemen, judges, government officials, and respected institutions ... in such a way as to create disrespect for established authority." The use of the word "crime" was also regulated; overt sexuality was disallowed, and love stories needed to promote the 'sanctity of marriage' and so forth... Later CCA approved comics didn't follow these rules, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

The kids line of comics was Marvel Age/Adventures, now replaced by the "Marvel Universe" cartoon block on Disney XD, with two titles thus far:

- Ultimate Spider-Man Adventures
- The Avengers: Earth's Mightiest Heroes Adventures

Wikipedia article w/ collection list: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvel_Adventures